# Error You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with activity

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, runtime-error, logcat

I am working on anroid application, as it run fine with dark action bar but when I change this to no action bar the app crashes and show me this error in logcat.

[image: Logcat Error]

I have make changes with the style and xml file but remains same issue. As I again ad Dark action bar it start working fine.

the links I have studied

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Here is my style file

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorText</item>
</style>
```

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.UsersListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Comment: If you are using AppTheme then try to replace LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity with LoginActivity extends Activity

Comment: just a moment I am trying

Comment: I did'nt understand your point, would you kindly make me understand...?

Comment: us above thing in your LoginActivity  class or add theme in manifest where your login activity is declared

Comment: this make more problems and it says create getter and shows red line under  the created methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution is change the Java inheritance from ActionBarActivity to Activity and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is, a non Theme.AppCompat value

In your case issue is with your manifest file you haven't specified `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` inside activities tag

Go your manifest file and replace splash activity with this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Inside your splash activity class do this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Theme.AppCompat value where it actually locates??

Comment: I have changed the inheritance but as I changed It shows red line under the already created methods

Comment: @ziikhankhan you need to show us the detailed error you're getting regarding the red line your getting take a screen shot and show us

Comment: as I migrated the type to the app.appcompatactivity it shows me error

 error: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar()

Comment: Problem is not in your login activity class your logcat shows that problem is with splash activity

Comment: Noo there's a change in manifest file you haven't specified theme for splash activity in manifest file

Comment: splash activity is the problem your logcat clearly shows it

Comment: after deleting splash activity the problem remains the same

Comment: share logcat screenshot after deleting splash activity

Comment: Go to your manifest file and inside all activities specify android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: @ziikhankhan check updated answer and please mark correct